# Lowercase property names from Json() in .Net core

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core

Have class ClientViewModel:

```
public class Result
{      
  public long PKID
  {
      get;
      set;
  }

   public string Name
   { 
      get; 
      set; 
   }
}
```

And have post method to return this model:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Search(string orderBy, List<Order> order, Search search,
        int start, int length, string searchTerm, bool isAsc, bool hideVoidedAndDeclined, bool recent = false)
    {
        var take = length;
        var skip = start;
        var m = _clientsService.Search(searchTerm, orderBy, hideVoidedAndDeclined, isAsc, take, skip, recent);


        return Json(m);
    }
```

but when try to return object in json it looks as:

```
name:"Nick22"
pkid: 5
```

But i need to save register

```
Name:"Nick22"
PKID: 5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *should* change the contractresolver. But since your casing is not always the same, you might be better off using

`services.AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });`

Comment: AddJsonOptions - didnt see this method

Comment: Was solved problem. Just need to write 
     `services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            }); ;`