# Why the controller response are setting model field names into lower case?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my .NET Core project, in the response of all controllers, the object fields are coming in lower case **in the first one or two letters of the field name**:

```
{
  "iD_PARAM": "foo",
  "cD_PROM": "bar",
  "txT_OFFICER": "lorem",
  "cN_NEW_PARAM": "fubá",
  "iD_SITUATION": "XX",
  "iD_NEW_USER": "ipsun",
}
```

It's strange, because the model has all fields in UPPER case:

```
public partial class MyModel {
   public long ID_PARAM { get; set; }
   public long CD_PROM { get; set; }
   public string TXT_OFFICER { get; set; }
   public int CN_NEW_PARAM { get; set; }
   public int ID_SITUATION { get; set; }     
   public int ID_NEW_USER { get; set; }  
}
```

For more detail, this is the controller where I set the values and the response:

```
[HttpPost("receive")]

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
      try
      {
        MyModel newParam = new MyModel ();

        newParam.ID_PARAM = "foo";
        newParam.CD_PROM = "foo";
        newParam.TXT_OFFICER = "lorem";
        newParam.CN_NEW_PARAM = "fubá";
        newParam.ID_SITUATION = "XX";
        newParam.ID_NEW_USER = "ipsun";

        return Ok(newParam);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        return BadRequest(ex);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Check the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Newtonsoft Json, if you want your Json properties to be uppercase, try decorating your Model with JsonProperty like this to prevent the Serializer try to infer the property name :

```
public partial class MyModel {
  [JsonProperty("ID_PARAM")]
  public long ID_PARAM { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("CD_PROM")]
  public long CD_PROM { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("TXT_OFFICER")]
  public string TXT_OFFICER { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("CN_NEW_PARAM")]
  public int CN_NEW_PARAM { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("ID_SITUATION")]
  public int ID_SITUATION { get; set; }     
  [JsonProperty("ID_NEW_USER")]
  public int ID_NEW_USER { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: Mauricio, it worked. The annotation sollution solved the problem. 
I'm still curious, I'm wonder why .NET works in this way...
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `ContractResolver`, just add below code in startup ConfigurSservices

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
```

Refer to [Lowercase property names from Json() in .Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301781/lowercase-property-names-from-json-in-net-core)