# Don't read web api information in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm learning Angular و and want to add WebApi created in Asp .Net Core به to my project but I'm having trouble printing the information.

Step 1: app.module.ts

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule],
```

Step 2: person-servise.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IPerson } from 'src/IPerson';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonServiseService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  private Url:string='https://localhost:44365/api/todo';
  getDate():Observable<IPerson[]>
  {
    return  this.http.get<IPerson[]>(this.Url);
  }
}
```

Step3: Create IPerson in Src

```
export interface IPerson
{
    Id:number,
    FName:string,
    LName:string,
    Age:number
}
```

Step 4: app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonServiseService } from './person-servise.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ProjectTwo';
  constructor(private _persen:PersonServiseService){  } 
  ngOnInit(){
    this._persen.getDate().subscribe(data=> this.persen=data);
  }
  persen:any[]=[];
}
```

Step 5: app.component.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let item of persen">
    <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.FName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.LName}}</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tested the WebApi created using Asp .Net Core Post with Postman software, and the Get, Post, Put, Delete operation works fine but does not appear in the Angular output.

the attachment:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> There was only one question for me that I used uppercase in my Prop, so why convert to lowercase? –

You could avoid using lowercase property name by setting below configuration in your asp.net core web api startup.cs.

If you use asp.net core 2.2, just use:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

If you use asp.net core 3.0+, add a package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.0.0) for your version and use:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {                
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

    });
```

Refer to [Why the controller response are setting model field names into lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193412/why-the-controller-response-are-setting-model-field-names-into-lower-case/58194410#58194410)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you are reassigning reference of this.persen in the subscription. Your view still referes to the reference created by this:
 persen:any[]=[];

Either add your elements in the subsription block to your existing persen array or use async binding in view

Answer (score 0):

In typescript / javascript casing matters. Your casing in your template is different than the casing of the properties/fields that are being returned in the api call. Fix either the server side or the client side code so they are the same.

Example:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let item of persen">
  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
  <td>{{item.fName}}</td>
  <td>{{item.lName}}</td>
</tbody>
```

```
export interface IPerson
{
    id:number,
    fName:string,
    lName:string,
    age:number
}
```

Comment: How do I do this?
Please explain more? Is it a problem with WebApi?

Comment: Your example looks exactly like my code, what's the difference?

Comment: @Aliakbar - `item.fName` is *not* the same as `item.FName`. Your casing is different (casing is F or f, one is upper case and one is lower case). Javascript / Typescript are case sensitive.

Comment: @Aliakbar - Your picture of the returned json the casing is camel case but your typescript uses pascal casing. Those are not the same and you can't interchange them and expect them to reference the same property/field.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was solved dear friend.
There was only one question for me that I used uppercase in my Prop, so why convert to lowercase?

Comment: @Aliakbar - Your c# properties were pascal case but the json serializer will convert the properties to camel case by default. So your fields client side must match that and also use camel case. Camel casing is a defacto standard for property casing in javascript and json hense that behavior server side.

Comment: @Aliakbar if this solved your problem please consider marking an answer using the check mark on the left side of the answer you wish to mark. You can only mark a single answer as "the answer" per question but you can always upvote any answer you felt added to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that the JSON that is retured by the API is camel case and not pascal case (as the properties in C# are).
In Typescript properties are case sensitive so, you should follow the camel case property naming and not pascal case naming.

If you want to preserve the camel casing you can use in > .NET Core 3

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(jo => jo.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)
```

prior versions must use

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(jo=> jo.UseMemberCasing())
```